How to generate unique log files with Slf4j and logback?
I have a spring boot application that uses Slf4j and logback.
This application contains the following class:
@Component
public class CustomFileLogger {
    private FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> mainLogAppender;

    // Start logging to the main log directory
    public void startMainLog(String uniquePath, String uniqueId) {
        mainLogAppender = createFileAppender(uniquePath + "/" + uniqueId + ".log", uniqueId);
        attachAppender(mainLogAppender);
    }

    // Create a file appender
    private FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> createFileAppender(String filePath, String uniqueId) {
        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

        FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = new FileAppender<>();
        fileAppender.setContext(context);
        fileAppender.setName(uniqueId);
        fileAppender.setFile(filePath);

        PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
        encoder.setContext(context);
        encoder.setPattern("[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%thread] [%level] [%logger{0}.%M:%line] - %msg%n");
        encoder.start();

        fileAppender.setEncoder(encoder);
        fileAppender.start();

        return fileAppender;
    }

    // Attach appender to root logger
    private void attachAppender(FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> appender) {
        Logger rootLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(org.slf4j.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        rootLogger.addAppender(appender);
    }

    // Stop logging and remove the main log appender
    public void stopMainLog() {
        Logger rootLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(org.slf4j.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        if (mainLogAppender != null) {
            rootLogger.detachAppender(mainLogAppender);
            mainLogAppender.stop();
            mainLogAppender = null;
        }
    }
}

CustomFileLogger class is being used by this class:
@Setter
@Slf4j
public abstract class AbstractService {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    protected ServiceA serviceA;

    @Autowired
    protected ServiceB serviceB;

    protected Params params;

    protected CustomFileLogger customFileLogger;

    public void process() {
        try {
            customFileLogger = applicationContext.getBean(CustomFileLogger.class);
            customFileLogger.startMainLog(params.getUniquePath(), params.getUniqueID());

            prepareData();
            generateReport();
            
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            handleExeption(e);
        } finally {
            customFileLogger.stopMainLog();
        }
    }
    // other methods
}

The desired behavior is to have each instance of an AbstractService subclass logging messages to a dedicated file based on a unique ID and path associated with that instance. I have several prototype-scoped subclasses (SubclassA, SubclassB, and SubclassC) that run sequentially, each sharing a unique ID and path for the current run.
For example, if uniqueId = xptoID, I expect all log messages from SubclassA, SubclassB, and SubclassC instances with this unique ID to be appended to a single log file named xptoID.log.
The problem is that, when multiple instances of a subclass (e.g., multiple SubclassA instances) run concurrently, log messages intended for one unique log file sometimes end up in files belonging to other instances. This results in log files that contain messages from different, unrelated executions.
